# How can I write one method to control all of the labels or textView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel, uitextview

I have many `Labels`, `TextView` and `TextField` in different pages. How can I write a method to control all of the labels or textView in their font type, font size, or to check 6 textfield’s is empty or not? Is there a way for that? Instead of writing long code like this

```
 if ((txtfldFirst.text && txtfldFirst.text.length && txtfldLast.text && txtfldLast.text.length && txtfldPhone.text && txtfldPhone.text.length && txtfldEmail.text && txtfldEmail.text.length && txtViewComment.text && txtViewComment.text.length) )


[txt1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GalaxiePolaris-Book" size:16.0]];
[txt2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GalaxiePolaris-Book" size:16.0]];
[txt3 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GalaxiePolaris-Book" size:16.0]];
[txt4 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GalaxiePolaris-Book" size:16.0]];
...
.....
```

Comment: Instead create a subclasses for label, textview and textfield would be much efficient  and redundant.

Comment: Could you show me a way for that? If I made a create a subclass am I going to connect each of label, textview and textfield to that class? I didn't understand it. @Kampai

Comment: For example: Create a subclass of `UILabel` add all properties like font, size, color etc in `initWithFrame:` method. So that now you just need to create object of that subclass and all properties will be override to that label.

Comment: Ok I will try it. @Kampai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass.

```
New file -> iOS -> Source -> Cocoa Touch Class -> 
-> MyLabel; subclass of UILabel
```

in .m file write:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GalaxiePolaris-Book" size:16.0];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then in your controller or view instead of

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

write:

```
MyLabel *label = [[MyLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: It's also a good pattern to create MyConfigs file and declare UIFont there. This will keep all such configurable things in one place.